# Enqueuing Script in WordPress while doing Webpack-Dev-Server HMR

Tags: wordpress, webpack, webpack-hmr

I'm trying to be a good WordPress Citizen  and including my JavaScript the right way, via `wp_enqueue_scripts` in my `functions.php`.

However doing it this way I don't get **hot module reloading** (hmr) via **webpack-dev-server** to work.

Can anybody give me a hint or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No reaction here, so I was forced to look for an answer by myself. 
Here it is.

What I did not get was how to make the `bundle.js` file, which **webpack-dev-server** makes available just in memory, available to WordPress using `wp_enqueue_scripts` in the `functions.php`.

my **webpack.config.js** (extract)

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/entry.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  devServer: {
    open: true,
    hot: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    proxy: {
      '/': {
        target: 'http://wordpress:8888/',
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

The thing is: Although I proxy the dev-sever through my MAMP-server, which runs under `http://wordpress:8888` the `build.js` file is not made available by **webpack-dev-server** under `http://wordpress:8888/build.js` but under the original url, which is `http://localhost:8080/build.js`.

Once I got that a conditional statement in the `functions.php` did the trick.

my **functions.php** (extract)

```
<?php

// Load my JS
if (!defined('WP_ENVIRONMENT') || WP_ENVIRONMENT == "production") {

  function reactTheme_enque_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'react-theme-js',
      get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bundle.js',
      [], // dependencies could go here
      time(), // version for caching
      true // loading it within footer
    );
  }

} else {

  function reactTheme_enque_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
      'react-theme-js',
      'http://localhost:8080' . '/bundle.js',
      [], // dependencies could go here
      time(), // version for caching
      true // loading it within footer
    );
  }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'reactTheme_enque_scripts');

?>
```

So by now just adding one line within the `wp-config.php` I can WordPress make looking for the `bundle.js` file, where **webpack-dev-server** is putting it.
If this line is missing, it loads the `bundle.js` file from the root of the theme directory.

my **wp-config.php** (extract)

```
define('WP_ENVIRONMENT', 'development');
```

Comment: Awesome...thats what i also was looking for..thanks..lots of time saving..

Comment: Is it inserting the css on the fly...?? for me this works fine but the full reload is happeing for all js or css file updates..

Comment: Have you tried changing the output.publicPath value? For me, *hot-update.json files were on the wrong domain, so I had to change output.publicPath (the issue is described here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1591)

Comment: I'm trying to run this setup and getting error -> Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'publicPath'. These properties are valid:
   object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Comment: I've replaced it with static: { directory: path.join(__dirname, '/')} but then I see all the folders instead https://imgur.com/W9nlQxW What I'm doing incorrectly?